# How to change style class when an event has been triggered in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a simple list of items in my component and want to change the style when a item has been selected. Currently I tried this by using v-bind:class and a boolean variable which will be changed when the event has been triggered. I debugged it but it does not work, the class of the list element stays always "list-group-item" instead of the expected "list-group-item active"

```
        <template>


                    <li     class="list-group-item"
                            style="cursor: pointer"
                            v-bind:class="{active: isActive}"
                            @click="serverSelected">
                        <p> Server <span class="badge badge-secondary">{{ server.id }}</span> [status = {{server.status}}]</p>
                    </li>

        </template>

        <script>
            import { eventBus } from '../../main'
            export default{
                props:['server'],
                methods:{
                    serverSelected: function(){
                        this.isActive = !this.isActive;
                        console.log("active value is: " + this.isActive);
                        eventBus.$emit('serverSelected', this.server);
                        console.log('server selected ' + this.server.id);
                    }
                },
                data:{
                    isActive: false
                }
            }
        </script>

        <style>

        </style>
```

Comment: So you don't have warnings/errors in the browser console when the component loads/li item is clicked?

Comment: `data` should be a function https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` [should be a function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function), so that each instance can maintain an independent copy of the returned data object

```
data: function () {
  return {
     isActive: false
  }
}
```